# Access hidden elements width and height

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ref

I am trying to access the subcontext menu's width and height. They are styled `display: none` until hovered on the parent element. The structure goes as

```
const Parent = styled.div`
    p{
      display:none;
    }
    &:hover{
        p{
           display:block;
           width: 200px;
           height:250px;
           overflow:auto; 
        }
    }
`
class ParentComponent extends {Component}{
    state={}

    menuRef = React.createRef(); 

    render(){
       return(
         <Parent>
           <Child menuRef={menuRef}>
         </Parent>

       )
    }
}
```

Since the element has display none on load, it is showing the `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight` to be `0`. Do I have to go to `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` and control the hover styling? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using

```
visibility: hidden
```

instead is using display

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
opacity: 0
```

instead of

```
display: none
```